# Do other countries have a oral exam system similar to French “colles”?

Tags: undergraduate, education

The French [*classes prépas*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Classe_preparatoire_aux_grandes_ecoles) system includes, during the first two years of undergraduate (post-baccalaureate) education, a series of regular oral exams, known as *colles*. Basically: every week during your first two years, you have two oral exams, each lasting one hour, with one teacher examining two or three students, each using a blackboard. A science student would typically have math and chemistry on week A, then physics and another topic (engineering, foreign language, …) on week B. This system prepares students for national competitive exams after their second year, which includes both written and oral components.

Now, whenever I have to explain that system to a foreign colleague, I have to do it from the start (as above) because I do not know any other similar system they might know (especially, I don't know of any equivalent or similar system in the US). Is there one?

Comment: That sounds nothing like any system that I know of in the US. But I'm not sure that "no" constitutes an answer, hence posting as a comment...

Comment: And it must be noted that this is a minority system (13.3% of the "bac général" students are going in "classes prépas", and 1.4% of the "bac technologique" students).

Comment: I also haven't heard about anything like this. The closest thing I've heard of are the comprehensive exams in fields like chemistry in graduate schools as part of the qualification procedures. But those exams are all still chemistry, not a mixture of different disciplines.

Comment: This question is perfect for this SE new site: http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/49571/teachers-school if you find it useful you can follow and make it more popular

Comment: In Poland usually there are two final (i.e. end of the semester) exams for each subject - one written, and one oral.

Comment: This question is perfect for this SE new site: [undergraduates](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/49571/teachers-school) if you find it useful you can follow it and help us in spreading the word about it.

Comment: @PiotrMigdal please consider adding the polish system to my CW answer.

Comment: @DanielE.Shub I might misread the question (or it was vague), but in Poland there are oral exams for university courses (which IMHO is way better than only a test or written exam, but also more time consuming; I heard that such thing is rare in UK/US), but there are usually no for admission (at least in STEM). I don't know French system, so for me it's hard to compare (or OK, I can ask French guy in my group).

Comment: I did not get! This so-called `colles` is two-years of four-year undergraduate programs for `BSc`? or it is a preparatory program before entering university?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct answer to this question is either *yes* or *no*. To answer *yes* one would simply need to provide a single example of another country with an oral exam system similar to the French system. To answer *no* we would need confirmation that no other country uses a similar system. To start the alphabetical list:

- United Kingdom: Undergraduate students at the top universities tend to begin their studies immediately following their A-Level examinations which do not have a substantial oral component.
- United States of America: Undergraduate students at the top universities tend to begin their studies immediately following their high school/secondary education. Admission is based upon performance throughout high school and standardize test neither of which have a substantial oral component.

Comment: I think that the question was on the undergraduate studies, not on the admission procedure (unless I misread). I'm willing to contribute, but first I need to know if we are writing about the same thing.

Comment: I agree with @PiotrMigdal, it is interesting to know that if other universities take oral exams for their current students or just using paper exams!

Answer (score 1):

I'm from Serbia and study at the Faculty of Philosophy. Almost all exams are oral, except for some that require you write a paper on a topic of your choice. We  also have a few courses that require tests, that you have to pass so you can take an oral exam. This system is used for all humanities studies and other social studies as far as I am aware of.

Comment: If it is in Serbia, it must be popular in the Eastern Europe.

Answer (score 1):

There may be oral exams in others country but as far as I know there is nothing like "colles", colles aren't "exams", they are trainings for the oral part of a national competition.

The reason is simple: the classe prépa / Grande Ecole system is unique to france. The main reason to go to "classe prépa" is not to learn but to go to the best "grande ecole".

Answer (score 1):

This is the same system in Russia and it’s the standard. Although not once every two weeks as you describe. They are more like end of semester exams. Usually students will be given a list of 30 questions on the subject. Let’s say it’s chemistry.

The students will have to know how to answer all these questions, as 2 will be asked at random by the professor on exam day. Students should talk for about 5 minutes for each question. So actually the professors have the longer working day going through all the students. And students come in for their 10 minute slot. I believe this system is only in universities.

Answer (score 0):

In Italy almost all exams are oral. We get used to it since elementary school.